# Nested SQL Query - logical issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing some problems creating a SQL query.

In my database I have two tables, rooms and reservations and the tables are structured like that:

**Table : rooms**

```
roomID : int (PK, auto increment, unique)
description : varchar
capacity : int
```

**Table : reservations**

```
resID : int (PK, auto increment, unique)
roomID : int (FK)
date : date
beginning : time
end : time
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to create a query, which returns a list of rooms regarding some passed arguments. There should not be two or more reservations for a room at the same time.

In plain English the query would be something like:

```
SELECT description from rooms 
WHERE capacity is greater or equal to :passedCapacity
AND date not equal to :passedDate
OR date is equal to :passedDate BUT 
:passedBeginning and :passedEnd do not collide with other reservations
```

I have no idea how to do that.

Would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all reservations that overlap, then you will need some sort of `join`.  You can, however, do this with an `exists` clause, as in:

```
select r.*
from reservations r
where exists (select 1
              from reservations r2
              where r2.roomId = r.roomId and
                    r2.date = r.date
                    r2.resid <> r.resid and
                    r2.beginning < r.end and
                    r2.end > r.beginning
             );
```

This uses the logic that two time periods overlap when the first begins before the second ends and the first ends after the second begins.